What's the origin of the hole in King Tut's death mask?
On the right hand side of King Tutankhamun's death mask there's a small but noticeable hole.
Is the origin known?
The craftsmanship of the mask is superb, if it's a manufacturing defect it's hard to believe that either it wasn't spotted at the time or the craftsman lacked the skills to fix it. On the other hand it's nearly as hard to believe that Howard Carter damaged it during the excavation - he was known for the care and attention to detail of his work. It's also odd that if it was damaged at discovery it wasn't repaired at the time.
So what's the story behind it?

Image comes from the Wikipedia page, apparently dated 2016. The damage is also visible in some earlier black and white images. There's a picture of the mask in-situ (presumably circa 1925) but the area of interest is covered in black gunk.

An image from wikipedia, also listed as 1925, clearly shows the damage already existing even then.

This small hole or flaw is not a bullet hole.  It has not been definitively attributed to any particular event, such as a deliberate act or modern mishandling, but rather is a characteristic of the artifact's unique history and creation.  It is believed to have occurred prior to modern discovery.

@JMS - thanks for the answer, can you provide any sources or references?

@ConanTheGerbil I took the liberty of removing the "bullet" from "bullet hole" in the title, because it is likely detracting from possible answers. I think we can all agree that it being an actual bullet hole is very, very unlikely.

@JMS believed by whom?

@JMS If you have a source for that assertion, I'd say it's a good answer.

According to Egyptologist Nicholas Reeves, 'Tutankhamun's Mask Reconsidered', in: A. Oppenheim and O. Goelet (eds.), The Art and Culture of Ancient Egypt: Studies in Honor of Dorothea Arnold (Bulletin of the Egyptological Seminar 19), New York 2015, pp. 514-515:

"A second group of very different injuries is visible to both the front and the outer edge of the mask’s right lappet: two crudely punched holes made in antiquity to receive a wire to hold the royal flail firmly in position. Quite why this fixing had been required, and why it had been realized in this crude manner, are questions that obviously warrant consideration. A likely explanation is that the Opening of the Mouth ceremony required the king’s mummy to be physically raised from the horizontal to the vertical, in which position the unsupported flail will have been found to fall awkwardly forward or sideways. Presumably, from its poor quality, the necessary remedial work took place on site and at a relatively late and urgent stage in the proceedings. Since it is difficult to imagine the day of burial having been disrupted by the hammering required, we might speculate that the modification had been carried out during or following a practice run-through of the funeral ceremony. Referring back to the losses of inlay noted above: it is apparent from Harry Burton’s in situ photographs that several sections of blue glass were already missing from the right lappet in particular, close to the punched holes, before Carter embarked upon his removal of the mask from its solidified resin bed. The inference to be drawn is that a proportion of these preburial losses had been inflicted during the course of attaching this flail retention wire."

